Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in nextjs
In my project there is an one dependency better-sqlite3.
This dependency is working fine.But after some time i am getting the fs module not found error again and again.


I tried all the methods like reinstall the dependencies,clear cache but nothing worked.

Maybe this can help: https://sentry.io/answers/module-not-found-nextjs/

You cannot use fs module in a browser. Make sure to only use it in server-side  rendering.
